# Update price of a WooCommerce product in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the prices of various products on my <kbd>WooCommerce website</kbd>, but I have a problem. When I run the script, if I change `correctly` in the database and goals, the front of the web still appears as the wrong prices, even some prices appear "Free".

The strangest thing of all is that by entering the product edition if I see the prices correctly.

I give you the code sample:

```
$stock          = $value['stock'];
$regular_price  = $value['rates']['2']['rate_pvp'];

update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price',    $regular_price);
update_post_meta($post_id, '_price',            $regular_price);

$product->set_price($regular_price);

if($stock>0){
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
} else {
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock_status', 'outofstock');
}

update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock', $stock);

echo $post_id . ':' . $value['variation_sku'] . ':' . $stock . '.............................OK<br/>';

wc_delete_product_transients();
```

Comment: Any cache plugin ?

Comment: None, only woocommerce

Comment: Try pressing `CTRL-SHIFT-R` whilst on the site to refresh your browsers cache

Comment: tried switching theme?

Comment: Use `$product->set_sale_price()` and `$product->set_regular_price()`.

Comment: Where does $product come from in the code?

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem. i think that you should reset the query object of wordpress. Here my sample that work properly.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',  'product_cat' => $key);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product; 
    update_post_meta($product->id, '_regular_price', (float)$value);
    update_post_meta($product->id, '_price', (float)$value);
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
```

I hope that this is useful.

Comment: Works for me, thanks.. but woocommerce 3.0.X is invalid ($product->id) it necessary change it for ($product->get_id())